# What is the 'x-content' property in CSS?

Tags: css

I've been looking through the stylesheet for [apple.com](https://www.apple.com/) and they use 'x-content' as a property. I can't see any documentation online as to its function?

[image]

Comment: By custom I meant *site specific*. They're probably not mean to render anything...just act as something for JS to grab on to. Just a guess though.